# Control for adding key/value pairs?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need a control to allow users to add/delete/edit rows of key/value pairs. What's the best control to use for this? Does anyone have an example? I'm quite new to WPF.

Comment: Can the user edit the existing key/value pairs in the list, or just add additional key/value pairs to the list?

Comment: @devdigital: Yes, editing would be helpful too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a simple dialogue with two labelled text boxes, the new pair would be added to the original data which should be bound to the `DataGrid` so that rows are generated automatically.

Edit: A DataGrid example solution.
XAML:

```
<Window
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:
In window class:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Pair> gridData = new ObservableCollection<Pair>(new Pair[]{new Pair()});
    public ObservableCollection<Pair> GridData
    {
        get { return gridData; }
    }
```

Pair class:

```
public class Pair : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string key = "Key";
    public string Key
    {
        get { return key; }
        set
        {
            if (this.key != value)
            {
                key = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Key");
            }
        }
    }


    private double value = 0;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            if (this.value != value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    public Pair() { }
    public Pair(string key, double value)
        : this()
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You should be able to add new pairs with the normal DataGrid functionality.

Comment: You can make a datagrid of textboxes? Do you have a XAML example? I'm new to WPF...

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks a lot! In general, with WPF, do you end up writing a lot of custom container classes so that they implement INotifyPropertyChanged, or IObservable?

Comment: A note to others: I didn't add the default/parameterless constructor to my "pair" type because I didn't need it anywhere... but you do have to add it if you want to be able to add more rows to the datagrid (it won't show a blank row otherwise). Took me awhile to figure that out.

Comment: In WPF you use INotifyPropertyChanged a lot to keep the UI updated, i normally try inherit from a simple custom class (BindableObject) that does nothing else than implement the interface. What you said about the parameterless constructor is interesting, i've been wondering why the row wasn't there with some datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MVVM, use an ObservableCollection of your pair type (or you could use the System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair type if you didn't want to define your own) on your view model.

You can provide the user with two textboxes to add a new pair, which instantiates your pair type and adds it to the ObservableCollection.  You can use commands to invoke a method on your view model to do this (or look into a framework such as Caliburn.Micro which supports convention based binding of view controls such as buttons to verbs on your view model).

You could use a ListBox to display the collection of pairs (just bind the ItemsSource property on the ListBox to the view models ObservableCollection of pairs).  Alternatively, if you want to support inline editing of existing pairs, then the DataGrid would be a good choice.  The DataGrid supports inline editing by double clicking a cell value.  You can define a normal cell template and an editing cell template in the DataGrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyPairsCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Key">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I get this error when I try using `public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Variables { get; set; }` as my container: "A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Value' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]'." -- **Edit:** I mean when I try double clicking a row in the datagrid.... (I think inline editing might be nicer)

Comment: @me: Didn't think KeyValuePairs had read-only values... but maybe they do. Answer is to implement your own key/value type as HB suggests.