# WPF DataGrid Key Value where Value can be Array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to build a control that Allows the user to enter Key Value Pairs.

Currently I'm just using a DataGrid which works great, but ...

In some cases though value could another set of Key Value Pairs.

Ultimately the users input will be converted to JSON .. so the final output could be

```
{
    Key1 : "Value1",
    Key2 : "Value2",
    Key3 : {
               SubKey1 : "SValue1",
               SubKey2 : "SValue2"
           }
}
```

Is there an existing control that does what I'm looking for \ what's the easiest way to achieve the above.

Comment: Hmm just doing some quick searching I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662705/control-for-adding-key-value-pairs . Does this help you at all?

Comment: It seems like this answer is on how to do what I already have. Adding multiple Key Value pairs. What I need is to be able to add an array of Key Value Pairs as one of the values in some cases.